# Continuity and reducing the problem from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine if $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ $$f \, (x,y) \,  = 
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}, & \text{if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$,}  \\[6pt]
> 0,                       & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$.}
> \end{cases}$$ is continuous at the origin.

I previously posted the same question, but I didn't quite get the point through what I was asking. So for the start, it's clear that $\frac{\sin(t)}{t} \to 1$, when $t \to 0$ this can be easily shown with L'Hopitals rule. However, what I would like to understand is how can we simply reduce the problem from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ simply just letting $x^2+y^2 = t$ and then using the result I stated earlier. This doesn't quite make sense to me that we can just use the case of one-dimensional function and then deduce that the same thing holds in $\mathbb{R}^2.$

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change into polar coordinates and get the function:
$$f(r,\theta)=\frac{sin(r^2)}{r^2}$$
$f$ now turned into a function of  a single variable, and you can use L'hospital to take the limit.

Polar coordinates are useful for a wider class of functions, so it's useful for you to know this technique.

Comment: I'm not familiar with polar coordinates, unfortunately...

Comment: It is not necessary to transform to polar coordinates.  A simple substitution $x^2+y^2=s$, for $s\ge 0$ suffices.

Comment: It's maybe the most common tool in finding limits of functions of two variables - I'd suggest you to read about it because it's extremely useful. But in this particular case, it gives a similar result to the change of variable you suggested with $t$.

Comment: @MarkViola I agree that in this case it's a good method, I'm suggesting this as a general method for OP since it's useful for a wider class of functions, and it also gives a geometrical understanding of how the limit is taken.

Comment: This function is clearly not continuous at the origin as it is not defined at the origin. Perhaps you meant to have a piecewise function that removes the discontinuity at $(0,0)$?

Comment: @user93370 clearly. I'm not changing the function OP gave.